# Challenges of modern implementations of Network "Time Travel" analysis

Tags: ids, time-travel

I was reading [this paper](http://www.icir.org/vern/papers/time-machine-sigcomm08.pdf) about the creation of network "time machines".  This paper has some interesting ideas but they're largely applied to "traditional" network environments.

What kind of challenges would be expected from trying to implement this kind of system in a modern cloud based environment using containerized applications, where identifiers like IP addresses and indeed whole systems tend to be ephemeral?

Comment: Please be more specific. You are asking for a research effort: reading 12 pages of a densely formatted document and then thinking about how it applies/do not apply to a specific case you are interested in.

Comment: And for whatever reasons someone thinks that this does not qualifiy as "too broad". Amazing... I am eager to see replies to this question!